# How to expand the range of view for Fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

The range of view in which the code below runs is small. Currently, it runs for the topmost part of a Fragment only.

The following is the code for setOnTouchListener:

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
view.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
            if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                texteffectskip = true
            }
            return@OnTouchListener true
        })
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment_main"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to run in the whole Fragment. I tried to adjust the height of the layout, but it wasn't helpful.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, View has ScrollView and ReyclerView.
I thought if i press ScrollView, View will be pressed.
but That's not true.
So I have to attach a TouchListener to the other view.

```
var scroller = view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_content) as ScrollView
scroller.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        texteffectskip = true
    }
    return@OnTouchListener true
})
```